# How to get more datas from database in a .tpl file in Prestashop

Tags: database, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on prestashop 1.7.
I added a field to the specific_price table.
I would like to use the data in this field in the cart-detailed-product-line.tpl

How should I do this ?
Do I need to connect to the price_specific table in the Cart.php class?
If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the simplest in view of your situation, is to create an override Link.php, and in there make a call to your table to fetch your information.

In the tpl you only have to put `{$link->nameoffunction(parametre)}`

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot [ethercreation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5172395/ethercreation)!!
I put in the Link.php :

```
public static function getSpecificPriceRatioAjout($id_product_attribute)
{
    $unit_price_ratio_ajout = Db::getInstance()->executeS(
        'SELECT unit_price_ratio_ajout FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price WHERE id_product_attribute = '.$id_product_attribute
    );
    var_dump($unit_price_ratio_ajout);
    return $unit_price_ratio_ajout;
}
```

In my .tpl :

```
{$link->getSpecificPriceRatioAjout({$product.id_product_attribute})}
```

The Response: *htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given*

Have you an ideo of what I've done wrong?

Comment: Try with :  $unit_price_ratio_ajout = Db::getInstance()->getValue(
        'SELECT unit_price_ratio_ajout FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price WHERE id_product_attribute = '.$id_product_attribute
    );

Comment: I don't know how to tell you how YOU ROCK ! ! ! ;)
Really, a big thank to you ! ! ! You save my week !

Comment: Ok please, thank you to close the application by validating the answer